# Add shipping address field in stock picking in odoo

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

When we `conform sale` from `sale order` it generate `stock picking` in `all transfer` and pass some fields by automatically like `oder id` as source document, partner id and other things to `stock picking` now i want to transfer another field with them  that is address of `partner_shipping_id` field. 
Someone please tell me how can i do it. I'll be very thankful ...

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "address of partner_shipping_id field"? The field itself is already used as `partner_id` for created picking.

Comment: When odoo generate `stock picking` and `stock move` from `sale order`  i want to pass some custom field values with data that odoo pass from sale order to `stock picking` and `stock move' ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following way you can solve your issue.

1.Set custom field on sale.order and stock.pirking in py as well as view side.
2.Inherit the stock.move  in your custom module and use the  **_prepare_picking_assign()** over ridding method.
3.Using `super` and set your custom field value.
4.View that changes After confirming of Sale Order document.

**For example :**

```
from openerp import models, fields, api, _

class sale_order(models.Model):
    _inherit='sale.order'
    customer_field=fields.Char(string='Customer Field')

class stock_picking(models.Model):
    _inherit='stock.picking'
    customer_field=fields.Char(string='Customer Field')    

class stock_move(models.Model):
    _inherit='stock.move'

def _prepare_picking_assign(self,cr, uid, move, context=None):
    res=super(stock_move,self)._prepare_picking_assign(cr, uid, move, context)
    if move.procurement_id and move.procurement_id.sale_line_id and move.procurement_id.sale_line_id.order_id:
        sale_obj = move.procurement_id.sale_line_id.order_id
        if sale_obj.dif_pick_address:
            res.update({
                'customer_field':sale_obj.customer_field,
            })
    return res
```

Above code is working fine in Odoo 8.0 version

Also, You should set in the view part so that you can check the sale order values come into stock picking after confirming your sale order.

I hope my answer may helpful for you :)

Comment: it is not passing data, that i enter in `customer_field` from sale order.  after pressing Confirm sale button customer_field in stock picking remain empty.

Comment: Above code is working fine in create invoice method on sale order is delivery order.I have tested well and also same working on my customer database.just check again properly and make own custom field and then check with that delivery flow with sale order document

Comment: @DASADIYACHAITANYA how its in odoo 12?